# Reading .csv file from a URL with some complications (Java/Selenium)

Tags: java, csv, selenium

I need to read (not download) a .csv file from a website that I log into with Selenium. There is a link in the webpage but instead of clicking it with selenium, I tried to use the code below. Let's say it's `https://a.com/templates/csv`

`InputStream input = new URL("https://a.com/templates/csv").openStream();`

When I try to read this with a Reader, I found out that I am actually reading the login page.

Is there a way to not open a new instance and read this file from the net?

Comment: It sounds like the server has a filter to checked if you're logged in and if not, bounce you to the log in page.  Did you make sure to establish an HttpSession to the server with the running code before hitting the url?

Comment: @MadConan thanks for your comment. I actually did not establish an HttpSession in my test code. I am running this in a UI automation suite where I log in and verify everything works fine. The .csv file is downloadable when the user clicks the link but I wanted to just read it off of the webpage. Is there a need to establish an HttpSession for this case?

Comment: There is if the application has functionality in place to ensure any request has an established session.